# Rename .app on OSX using Qt

Tags: macos, qt, rename

I am writing an updater application that downloads the files from the file server. Here is the sequence of operations:

1) Download the file from the server.

2) Rename the existing .app **(How to?)**

3) Move the downloaded app to the appropriate location.

Is there a best practice on OSX to rename the application programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `QDir::rename()`?

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#rename

I'm primarily a Windows/Linux Qt user so I can't help you out on the best practices for OS X.